# How to choose specific app to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, crop

There are more than one app that could handle CROP intent, but I only want gallery to do it without choosing because other app like google+ will have really bad rendering resolution, and choosing process doesn't have good user experience.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");  
Intent i = new Intent(intent);
ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
               res.activityInfo.name));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_CAMERA);
```

So how could I specify Gallery app to handle CROP Intent without user's choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could specify the package in your intent:

```
 intent.setPackage("com.android.gallery");
```

this will set an explicit application package name